# Deeplabcut stuck at ''Starting training....''

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, anaconda, conda

I try to use testscript.py to test DLC environment is work or not.
But is show some error and stuck at ''Starting training....''.

The following is what I do:

1. A win11 computer with i7-12700 and RTX3060
2. Install Anaconda
3. Install **CUDA 11.2** and **cuDNN 8.1**
4. Create environment by using offical DEEPLABCUT.yaml file
5. Enter environment and pip install Torch
6. Check if TF can use GPU
7. Run testscripy.py and stuck at "Starting training..."

Please help me solve this problem.
I think that may cause by some outdated packages.

The packages in environment:

```
# packages in environment at C:\App\anaconda3\envs\DEEPLABCUT:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
absl-py                   1.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
aom                       3.4.0                h0e60522_1    conda-forge
argon2-cffi               21.3.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
argon2-cffi-bindings      21.2.0           py38h294d835_2    conda-forge
asttokens                 2.0.8              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
astunparse                1.6.3                    pypi_0    pypi
attrs                     22.1.0             pyh71513ae_1    conda-forge
backcall                  0.2.0              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
backports                 1.0                        py_2    conda-forge
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.6.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
beautifulsoup4            4.11.1             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
bleach                    5.0.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
bzip2                     1.0.8                h8ffe710_4    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2022.6.15.1          h5b45459_0    conda-forge
cachetools                5.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
certifi                   2022.6.15.1              pypi_0    pypi
cffi                      1.15.1           py38hd8c33c5_0    conda-forge
charset-normalizer        2.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
colorama                  0.4.5              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
cycler                    0.11.0                   pypi_0    pypi
debugpy                   1.6.3            py38h885f38d_0    conda-forge
decorator                 5.1.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
deeplabcut                2.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
defusedxml                0.7.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
entrypoints               0.4                pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
executing                 1.0.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
expat                     2.4.8                h39d44d4_0    conda-forge
ffmpeg                    5.1.1           gpl_h7b28927_101    conda-forge
filterpy                  1.4.5                    pypi_0    pypi
flatbuffers               2.0.7                    pypi_0    pypi
flit-core                 3.7.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-dejavu-sans-mono 2.37                 hab24e00_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-inconsolata      3.000                h77eed37_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-source-code-pro  2.038                h77eed37_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-ubuntu           0.83                 hab24e00_0    conda-forge
fontconfig                2.14.0               hce3cb01_0    conda-forge
fonts-conda-ecosystem     1                             0    conda-forge
fonts-conda-forge         1                             0    conda-forge
fonttools                 4.37.1                   pypi_0    pypi
freetype                  2.12.1               h546665d_0    conda-forge
gast                      0.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
gettext                   0.19.8.1          ha2e2712_1008    conda-forge
glib                      2.72.1               h7755175_0    conda-forge
glib-tools                2.72.1               h7755175_0    conda-forge
google-auth               2.11.0                   pypi_0    pypi
google-auth-oauthlib      0.4.6                    pypi_0    pypi
google-pasta              0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
grpcio                    1.48.1                   pypi_0    pypi
gst-plugins-base          1.20.3               h001b923_1    conda-forge
gstreamer                 1.20.3               h6b5321d_1    conda-forge
h5py                      3.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
icu                       70.1                 h0e60522_0    conda-forge
idna                      3.3                      pypi_0    pypi
imageio                   2.21.2                   pypi_0    pypi
imgaug                    0.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
importlib-metadata        4.11.4           py38haa244fe_0    conda-forge
importlib_resources       5.9.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
ipykernel                 6.15.2             pyh025b116_0    conda-forge
ipython                   8.5.0              pyh08f2357_1    conda-forge
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                      py_1    conda-forge
ipywidgets                8.0.2              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
jedi                      0.18.1             pyhd8ed1ab_2    conda-forge
jinja2                    3.1.2              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
joblib                    1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jpeg                      9e                   h8ffe710_2    conda-forge
jsonschema                4.16.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter                   1.0.0            py38haa244fe_7    conda-forge
jupyter_client            7.3.5              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_console           6.4.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_core              4.11.1           py38haa244fe_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_pygments       0.2.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_widgets        3.0.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
keras                     2.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
keras-preprocessing       1.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
kiwisolver                1.4.4                    pypi_0    pypi
krb5                      1.19.3               h1176d77_0    conda-forge
libclang                  14.0.6                   pypi_0    pypi
libclang13                14.0.6          default_h77d9078_0    conda-forge
libffi                    3.4.2                h8ffe710_5    conda-forge
libglib                   2.72.1               h3be07f2_0    conda-forge
libiconv                  1.16                 he774522_0    conda-forge
libogg                    1.3.4                h8ffe710_1    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.37               h1d00b33_4    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.18               h8d14728_1    conda-forge
libsqlite                 3.39.3               hcfcfb64_0    conda-forge
libvorbis                 1.3.7                h0e60522_0    conda-forge
libxml2                   2.9.14               hf5bbc77_4    conda-forge
libxslt                   1.1.35               h34f844d_0    conda-forge
libzlib                   1.2.12               h8ffe710_2    conda-forge
llvmlite                  0.39.1                   pypi_0    pypi
lxml                      4.9.1            py38h294d835_0    conda-forge
markdown                  3.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
markupsafe                2.1.1            py38h294d835_1    conda-forge
matplotlib                3.5.3                    pypi_0    pypi
matplotlib-inline         0.1.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
mistune                   2.0.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
msgpack                   1.0.4                    pypi_0    pypi
msgpack-numpy             0.4.8                    pypi_0    pypi
nb_conda                  2.2.1                     win_6    conda-forge
nb_conda_kernels          2.3.1            py38haa244fe_1    conda-forge
nbclient                  0.6.8              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nbconvert                 7.0.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nbconvert-core            7.0.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nbconvert-pandoc          7.0.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nbformat                  5.4.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nest-asyncio              1.5.5              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
networkx                  2.8.6                    pypi_0    pypi
notebook                  6.4.12             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
numba                     0.56.2                   pypi_0    pypi
numexpr                   2.8.3                    pypi_0    pypi
numpy                     1.23.3                   pypi_0    pypi
oauthlib                  3.2.1                    pypi_0    pypi
opencv-python             4.6.0.66                 pypi_0    pypi
openh264                  2.3.0                h0e60522_0    conda-forge
openssl                   1.1.1q               h8ffe710_0    conda-forge
opt-einsum                3.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
packaging                 21.3               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pandas                    1.4.4                    pypi_0    pypi
pandoc                    2.19.2               h57928b3_0    conda-forge
pandocfilters             1.5.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
parso                     0.8.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
patsy                     0.5.2                    pypi_0    pypi
pcre                      8.45                 h0e60522_0    conda-forge
pickleshare               0.7.5                   py_1003    conda-forge
pillow                    9.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pip                       22.2.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pkgutil-resolve-name      1.3.10             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
ply                       3.11                       py_1    conda-forge
prometheus_client         0.14.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
prompt-toolkit            3.0.31             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
prompt_toolkit            3.0.31               hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
protobuf                  3.19.4                   pypi_0    pypi
psutil                    5.9.2            py38h91455d4_0    conda-forge
pure_eval                 0.2.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyasn1                    0.4.8                    pypi_0    pypi
pyasn1-modules            0.2.8                    pypi_0    pypi
pycparser                 2.21               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pygments                  2.13.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyparsing                 3.0.9              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyqt                      5.15.7           py38h75e37d8_0    conda-forge
pyqt5-sip                 12.11.0          py38h885f38d_0    conda-forge
pyrsistent                0.18.1           py38h294d835_1    conda-forge
python                    3.8.13          h9a09f29_0_cpython    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python-fastjsonschema     2.16.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python_abi                3.8                      2_cp38    conda-forge
pytz                      2022.2.1                 pypi_0    pypi
pywavelets                1.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pywin32                   303              py38h294d835_0    conda-forge
pywinpty                  2.0.7            py38hd3f51b4_0    conda-forge
pyyaml                    6.0                      pypi_0    pypi
pyzmq                     23.2.1           py38h09162b1_0    conda-forge
qt-main                   5.15.6               hf0cf448_0    conda-forge
qtconsole                 5.3.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
qtconsole-base            5.3.2              pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
qtpy                      2.2.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
requests                  2.28.1                   pypi_0    pypi
requests-oauthlib         1.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
rsa                       4.9                      pypi_0    pypi
ruamel-yaml               0.17.21                  pypi_0    pypi
ruamel-yaml-clib          0.2.6                    pypi_0    pypi
scikit-image              0.19.3                   pypi_0    pypi
scikit-learn              1.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
scipy                     1.9.1                    pypi_0    pypi
send2trash                1.8.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
setuptools                59.8.0                   pypi_0    pypi
shapely                   1.8.4                    pypi_0    pypi
sip                       6.6.2            py38h885f38d_0    conda-forge
six                       1.16.0             pyh6c4a22f_0    conda-forge
soupsieve                 2.3.2.post1        pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.39.3               hcfcfb64_0    conda-forge
stack_data                0.5.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
statsmodels               0.13.2                   pypi_0    pypi
svt-av1                   1.2.1                h0e60522_0    conda-forge
tables                    3.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tabulate                  0.8.10                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard               2.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard-data-server   0.6.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard-plugin-wit    1.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow                2.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-estimator      2.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem 0.27.0                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorpack                0.11                     pypi_0    pypi
termcolor                 1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
terminado                 0.15.0           py38haa244fe_0    conda-forge
tf-slim                   1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
threadpoolctl             3.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tifffile                  2022.8.12                pypi_0    pypi
tinycss2                  1.1.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.12               h8ffe710_0    conda-forge
toml                      0.10.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
torch                     1.12.1                   pypi_0    pypi
tornado                   6.2              py38h294d835_0    conda-forge
tqdm                      4.64.1                   pypi_0    pypi
traitlets                 5.3.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
typing_extensions         4.3.0              pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
ucrt                      10.0.20348.0         h57928b3_0    conda-forge
urllib3                   1.26.12                  pypi_0    pypi
vc                        14.2                 hb210afc_7    conda-forge
vs2015_runtime            14.29.30139          h890b9b1_7    conda-forge
wcwidth                   0.2.5              pyh9f0ad1d_2    conda-forge
webencodings              0.5.1                      py_1    conda-forge
werkzeug                  2.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
wheel                     0.37.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
widgetsnbextension        4.0.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
winpty                    0.4.3                         4    conda-forge
wrapt                     1.14.1                   pypi_0    pypi
wxpython                  4.0.7.post2              pypi_0    pypi
x264                      1!164.3095           h8ffe710_2    conda-forge
x265                      3.5                  h2d74725_3    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.6                h8d14728_0    conda-forge
zeromq                    4.3.4                h0e60522_1    conda-forge
zipp                      3.8.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
zstd                      1.5.2                h7755175_4    conda-forge
```

I sure TF can use my GPU by this:

```
(DEEPLABCUT) C:\Windows\system32>python
Python 3.8.13 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Mar 25 2022, 05:59:45) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
>>> print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
2022-09-11 20:41:50.137638: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2022-09-11 20:41:50.481875: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1616] Created device /device:GPU:0 with 9616 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 8.6
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 200595950863773239
xla_global_id: -1
, name: "/device:GPU:0"
device_type: "GPU"
memory_limit: 10083106816
locality {
  bus_id: 1
  links {
  }
}
incarnation: 14570387183940456862
physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 8.6"
xla_global_id: 416903419
]
```

Terminal stuck at "Starting training..."

```
(DEEPLABCUT) C:\works\DLC\DLC_script\DeepLabCut-master\DeepLabCut-master\examples>python testscript.py
Loading DLC 2.2.2...
Imported DLC!
On Windows/OSX tensorpack is not tested by default.
CREATING PROJECT
Created "C:\works\DLC\DLC_script\DeepLabCut-master\DeepLabCut-master\examples\TEST-Alex-2022-09-11\videos"
Created "C:\works\DLC\DLC_script\DeepLabCut-master\DeepLabCut-master\examples\TEST-Alex-2022-09-11\labeled-data"
Created "C:\works\DLC\DLC_script\DeepLabCut-master\DeepLabCut-master\examples\TEST-Alex-2022-09-11\training-datasets"
Created "C:\works\DLC\DLC_script\DeepLabCut-master\DeepLabCut-master\examples\TEST-Alex-2022-09-11\dlc-models"
Copying the videos
C:\works\DLC\DLC_script\DeepLabCut-master\DeepLabCut-master\examples\TEST-Alex-2022-09-11\videos\reachingvideo1.avi
Generated "C:\works\DLC\DLC_script\DeepLabCut-master\DeepLabCut-master\examples\TEST-Alex-2022-09-11\config.yaml"

A new project with name TEST-Alex-2022-09-11 is created at C:\works\DLC\DLC_script\DeepLabCut-master\DeepLabCut-master\examples and a configurable file (config.yaml) is stored there. Change the parameters in this file to adapt to your project's needs.
 Once you have changed the configuration file, use the function 'extract_frames' to select frames for labeling.
. [OPTIONAL] Use the function 'add_new_videos' to add new videos to your project (at any stage).
EXTRACTING FRAMES
Config file read successfully.
Extracting frames based on kmeans ...
Kmeans-quantization based extracting of frames from 0.0  seconds to 8.53  seconds.
Extracting and downsampling... 256  frames from the video.
256it [00:01, 214.77it/s]
Kmeans clustering ... (this might take a while)
Frames were successfully extracted, for the videos listed in the config.yaml file.

You can now label the frames using the function 'label_frames' (Note, you should label frames extracted from diverse videos (and many videos; we do not recommend training on single videos!)).
CREATING-SOME LABELS FOR THE FRAMES
Plot labels...
Creating images with labels by Alex.
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 5/5 [00:00<00:00,  6.01it/s]
If all the labels are ok, then use the function 'create_training_dataset' to create the training dataset!
CREATING TRAININGSET
Downloading a ImageNet-pretrained model from https://storage.googleapis.com/cloud-tpu-checkpoints/efficientnet/ckptsaug/efficientnet-b0.tar.gz....
The training dataset is successfully created. Use the function 'train_network' to start training. Happy training!
CHANGING training parameters to end quickly!
TRAIN
Selecting single-animal trainer
Config:
{'all_joints': [[0], [1], [2], [3]],
 'all_joints_names': ['bodypart1', 'bodypart2', 'bodypart3', 'objectA'],
 'alpha_r': 0.02,
 'apply_prob': 0.5,
 'batch_size': 1,
 'contrast': {'clahe': True,
              'claheratio': 0.1,
              'histeq': True,
              'histeqratio': 0.1},
 'convolution': {'edge': False,
                 'emboss': {'alpha': [0.0, 1.0], 'strength': [0.5, 1.5]},
                 'embossratio': 0.1,
                 'sharpen': False,
                 'sharpenratio': 0.3},
 'crop_pad': 0,
 'cropratio': 0.4,
 'dataset': 'training-datasets\\iteration-0\\UnaugmentedDataSet_TESTSep11\\TEST_Alex80shuffle1.mat',
 'dataset_type': 'default',
 'decay_steps': 30000,
 'deterministic': False,
 'display_iters': 2,
 'fg_fraction': 0.25,
 'global_scale': 0.8,
 'init_weights': 'C:\\App\\anaconda3\\envs\\DEEPLABCUT\\lib\\site-packages\\deeplabcut\\pose_estimation_tensorflow\\models\\pretrained\\efficientnet-b0\\model.ckpt',
 'intermediate_supervision': False,
 'intermediate_supervision_layer': 12,
 'location_refinement': True,
 'locref_huber_loss': True,
 'locref_loss_weight': 0.05,
 'locref_stdev': 7.2801,
 'log_dir': 'log',
 'lr_init': 0.0005,
 'max_input_size': 1500,
 'mean_pixel': [123.68, 116.779, 103.939],
 'metadataset': 'training-datasets\\iteration-0\\UnaugmentedDataSet_TESTSep11\\Documentation_data-TEST_80shuffle1.pickle',
 'min_input_size': 64,
 'mirror': False,
 'multi_stage': False,
 'multi_step': [[0.001, 5]],
 'net_type': 'efficientnet-b0',
 'num_joints': 4,
 'optimizer': 'sgd',
 'pairwise_huber_loss': False,
 'pairwise_predict': False,
 'partaffinityfield_predict': False,
 'pos_dist_thresh': 17,
 'project_path': 'C:\\works\\DLC\\DLC_script\\DeepLabCut-master\\DeepLabCut-master\\examples\\TEST-Alex-2022-09-11',
 'regularize': False,
 'rotation': 25,
 'rotratio': 0.4,
 'save_iters': 5,
 'scale_jitter_lo': 0.5,
 'scale_jitter_up': 1.25,
 'scoremap_dir': 'test',
 'shuffle': True,
 'snapshot_prefix': 'C:\\works\\DLC\\DLC_script\\DeepLabCut-master\\DeepLabCut-master\\examples\\TEST-Alex-2022-09-11\\dlc-models\\iteration-0\\TESTSep11-trainset80shuffle1\\train\\snapshot',
 'stride': 8.0,
 'weigh_negatives': False,
 'weigh_only_present_joints': False,
 'weigh_part_predictions': False,
 'weight_decay': 0.0001}
Batch Size is 1
C:\App\anaconda3\envs\DEEPLABCUT\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer_v1.py:1694: UserWarning: `layer.apply` is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Please use `layer.__call__` method instead.
  warnings.warn('`layer.apply` is deprecated and '
2022-09-11 20:18:35.578698: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2022-09-11 20:18:35.897924: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:42] Overriding orig_value setting because the TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH environment variable is set. Original config value was 0.
2022-09-11 20:18:35.898044: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1616] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 9616 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 8.6
Loading ImageNet-pretrained efficientnet-b0
2022-09-11 20:18:36.209153: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1616] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 9616 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 8.6
Switching to cosine decay schedule with adam!
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\App\anaconda3\envs\DEEPLABCUT\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\App\anaconda3\envs\DEEPLABCUT\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\App\anaconda3\envs\DEEPLABCUT\lib\site-packages\deeplabcut\pose_estimation_tensorflow\core\train.py", line 81, in load_and_enqueue
    batch_np = dataset.next_batch()
  File "C:\App\anaconda3\envs\DEEPLABCUT\lib\site-packages\deeplabcut\pose_estimation_tensorflow\datasets\pose_imgaug.py", line 404, in next_batch
    scmap_update = self.get_scmap_update(
  File "C:\App\anaconda3\envs\DEEPLABCUT\lib\site-packages\deeplabcut\pose_estimation_tensorflow\datasets\pose_imgaug.py", line 361, in get_scmap_update
    ) = self.compute_target_part_scoremap_numpy(
  File "C:\App\anaconda3\envs\DEEPLABCUT\lib\site-packages\deeplabcut\pose_estimation_tensorflow\datasets\pose_imgaug.py", line 498, in compute_target_part_scoremap_numpy
    j_x = np.asscalar(joint_pt[0])
  File "C:\App\anaconda3\envs\DEEPLABCUT\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 311, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("module {!r} has no attribute "
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'asscalar'
2022-09-11 20:18:38.298353: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:354] MLIR V1 optimization pass is not enabled
Training parameter:
{'stride': 8.0, 'weigh_part_predictions': False, 'weigh_negatives': False, 'fg_fraction': 0.25, 'mean_pixel': [123.68, 116.779, 103.939], 'shuffle': True, 'snapshot_prefix': 'C:\\works\\DLC\\DLC_script\\DeepLabCut-master\\DeepLabCut-master\\examples\\TEST-Alex-2022-09-11\\dlc-models\\iteration-0\\TESTSep11-trainset80shuffle1\\train\\snapshot', 'log_dir': 'log', 'global_scale': 0.8, 'location_refinement': True, 'locref_stdev': 7.2801, 'locref_loss_weight': 0.05, 'locref_huber_loss': True, 'optimizer': 'adam', 'intermediate_supervision': False, 'intermediate_supervision_layer': 12, 'regularize': False, 'weight_decay': 0.0001, 'crop_pad': 0, 'scoremap_dir': 'test', 'batch_size': 1, 'dataset_type': 'default', 'deterministic': False, 'mirror': False, 'pairwise_huber_loss': False, 'weigh_only_present_joints': False, 'partaffinityfield_predict': False, 'pairwise_predict': False, 'all_joints': [[0], [1], [2], [3]], 'all_joints_names': ['bodypart1', 'bodypart2', 'bodypart3', 'objectA'], 'alpha_r': 0.02, 'apply_prob': 0.5, 'contrast': {'clahe': True, 'claheratio': 0.1, 'histeq': True, 'histeqratio': 0.1, 'gamma': False, 'sigmoid': False, 'log': False, 'linear': False}, 'convolution': {'edge': False, 'emboss': {'alpha': [0.0, 1.0], 'strength': [0.5, 1.5]}, 'embossratio': 0.1, 'sharpen': False, 'sharpenratio': 0.3}, 'cropratio': 0.4, 'dataset': 'training-datasets\\iteration-0\\UnaugmentedDataSet_TESTSep11\\TEST_Alex80shuffle1.mat', 'decay_steps': 30000, 'display_iters': 2, 'init_weights': 'C:\\App\\anaconda3\\envs\\DEEPLABCUT\\lib\\site-packages\\deeplabcut\\pose_estimation_tensorflow\\models\\pretrained\\efficientnet-b0\\model.ckpt', 'lr_init': 0.0005, 'max_input_size': 1500, 'metadataset': 'training-datasets\\iteration-0\\UnaugmentedDataSet_TESTSep11\\Documentation_data-TEST_80shuffle1.pickle', 'min_input_size': 64, 'multi_stage': False, 'multi_step': [[0.001, 5]], 'net_type': 'efficientnet-b0', 'num_joints': 4, 'pos_dist_thresh': 17, 'project_path': 'C:\\works\\DLC\\DLC_script\\DeepLabCut-master\\DeepLabCut-master\\examples\\TEST-Alex-2022-09-11', 'rotation': 25, 'rotratio': 0.4, 'save_iters': 5, 'scale_jitter_lo': 0.5, 'scale_jitter_up': 1.25, 'covering': True, 'elastic_transform': True, 'motion_blur': True, 'motion_blur_params': {'k': 7, 'angle': (-90, 90)}, 'use_batch_norm': False, 'use_drop_out': False}
Starting training....
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect two issues here:

1. How long did you wait for? My setup has weaker hardware than yours and took almost 8 minutes before the first iterations showed.
2. Your error message clearly shows that `np.asscalar` isn't found. Your numpy version is `1.23.3`, but `np.asscalar` is deprecated since `1.16`. Maybe try downgrading (`pip install numpy==1.15` / `conda install numpy==1.15`) and see if the error persists.

Edit: I just checked the config file supplied by DLC and verified that no numpy version is specified. You should probably downgrade to a version <`1.16` since `np.asscalar` is used.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

1. Over 10 mins, still nothing happen. If the env is works, it should only take 2-3 mins to finish.

2. Downgrading isn't work. numpy version <1.16 can only install on python 3.7 and lower.
    And lower numpy version(such as 1.15.4) is incompatible with scipy.

Comment: I try to wait over night, and the first iterations doesn't showed.

Answer (score 0):

### (Update)

This is now fixed in the repository ([PR #1982](https://github.com/DeepLabCut/DeepLabCut/pull/1982)). If working from a `git clone` version of the DeepLabCut repository, then run a `git pull` to grab the latest version. Otherwise, they'll probably drop a release soon with the fix integrated.

---

### (Original Answer)

The `numpy.asscalar()` method was finally removed in NumPy 1.23 (see [Release Notes](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/release/1.23.0-notes.html?highlight=asscalar#expired-deprecations)) after being deprecated since v1.16. I added [an Issue to the repository](https://github.com/DeepLabCut/DeepLabCut/issues/1981). Unless you want to send in a Pull Request to fix it, downgrade the Numpy to 1.22 or below.

```
conda install -n DEEPLABCUT 'numpy <1.23'
```

#### Consider using Mamba

BTW, no one should be waiting for slow solves anymore - [Mamba](https://mamba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/mamba.html) has been stable for a long time and solved this issue. Once installed, just use the word `mamba` instead of `conda` for most commands.

```bash
conda install -n base conda-forge::mamba

mamba install -n DEEPLABCUT 'numpy <1.23'
```

#### Edit the YAML

Alternatively, edit the YAML to include the upper bound on `numpy`:

```yaml
  - numpy <1.23
```

and recreate the environment from the updated YAML.

Comment: I downgrade the Numpy to 1.22 and it works.
Thanks!!!

Comment: @Meng-XuanLiu FYI, the code in the repository is now fixed.